# Can Android camera software recognize a outdoor scene or object? (real-time object recognition)

Tags: android, image-processing, camera, augmented-reality, image-recognition

I read [this](http://people.csail.mit.edu/kapu/papers/nguyen_cvpr09.pdf) paper about real-time object recognition, and found it very interesting. I'm currently working on an location-aware app that is similar to the sport of orienteering.

For control point representation (a check point/waypoint) the initial idea was to use QR code scanning to verify a user of having been there; and thereby giving directions to the next control point.

Now it looks much more interesting to use some sort of natural object/scene recognition to verify users on a specific location in a route (if possible and effective).

Does anyone know more about this with specific code examples or experimentation, not just a conceptual presentation of it?

Comment: Any progress on your project? I was looking into doing something similar indoors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complex solutions and in early stages of development, prone to inaccuracies. Have a look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html) to begin with.